# How to get an Wacom Intuos CTH-480 to work under Easy Peasy 1.6 (Ubuntu 10.04)?

Tags: kernel-modules, tablet

Is there any way to make a Wacom Intuous CTH-480 work under Easy Peasy 1.6 (Ubuntu 10.04)?

I have installed the Wacom Driver files according these instruction, replacing 3.7 with 2.6.30, as Easy Peasy 1.6 uses kernel 2.6.32-21-generic:

http://matthewwittering.com/blog/ubuntu-tips/how-to-install-a-wacom-intuos-ctl-480-tablet-on-ubuntu.html

and I have installed

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom
```

The device is now detected as follows:

```
~$ xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]

⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ Macintosh mouse button emulation          id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos PT S Finger pad              id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos PT S Finger                  id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos PT S Pen eraser              id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos PT S Pen                     id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]

↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ Dell Dell USB Keyboard                    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ WebCam                                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
$lsusb | grep Wacom
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 056a:0302 Wacom Co., Ltd
~$ lsmod | grep wacom
wacom                  43114  0
```

Still, programs such as Mypaint (I am using version 0.8.2) don't 'see' the device.

- Can this be made to work?
- Do I have to upgrade to a newer Ubuntu distro / Kernel (I'd rather
  not, as I am perfectly satisfied with my current OS)? In case it is
  relevant: I'm using an Aspire One notebook.